# Python - Pygame For android errors

Tags: python, build, pygame

I was following [the documentation of pgs4a](http://pygame.renpy.org/android-packaging.html), where in the build part I got a `WindowsError [Error 2]`.
The Command and Traceback:

```
C:\Users\karuna\Desktop\Jython\Python\pgs4a-0.9.4>android.py build "C:\Users\karuna\Desktop\Jython\P
ython\pgs4a-0.9.4\mygame" release install

Updating build files.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\karuna\Desktop\Jython\Python\pgs4a-0.9.4\android.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\karuna\Desktop\Jython\Python\pgs4a-0.9.4\android.py", line 54, in main
    build.build(iface, args.argument[0], args.argument[1:])
  File "buildlib\build.py", line 301, in build
    build_core(iface, directory, commands)
  File "buildlib\build.py", line 221, in build_core
    subprocess.call([plat.android, "update", "project", "-p", '.', '-t', 'android-8', '-n', versione
d_name])
  File "C:\Python2.7 For Chintoo\lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python2.7 For Chintoo\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python2.7 For Chintoo\lib\subprocess.py", line 893, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

As obvious,
I am using Windows 7, and have:

- Python 2.7.3
- JDK
- Android Emulator
- Device drivers for my Sony Tipo.

Please help!
By the way,
I would prefer to get this running on my phone first. I am thinking of moving to the emulator later(after the tutorial is completed).

Is this question more suitable for https://android.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Do you have the android SDK tools directory in your $PATH?

Comment: @Wooble I have a system variable Android which leads to the the sdk tools directory

Comment: @Schoolboy Did you get rid of this issue? If yes, can you please post the solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is still an issue for you, but I ran into the similar issue recently and managed to solve it so I will just leave a note here.

If anyone gets this kind of error, go to pgs4a folder and android-sdk folder. There, run SDK Manager.exe file. You will see a list of Tools and different android versions. Try to find the version that you are working on and install everything that is 'uninstalled'.

I managed to solve the above issue by installing everything under my current AND previous Android versions. Hope this will help anyone who ran into the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

rename the folder android-sdk-windows to android-sdk

Comment: It doesn't help in my case. Its already android-sdk and still I'm getting this issue.